# installing adMob banner gives me strange Mach-O linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, banner

Hi i was trying to install adMob Ad in my app but xcode gives me this error

> ld: framework not found AudioUnit clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) ld: framework not found
>   AudioUnit

the audioUnit.framework was not to add (reading the tutorial i was following) but it gave me 3 errors saying that i needed it so in added but it gives me this error.
This is the code for the banner

```
//.h
//admob
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"
@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;

@interface ArrayDetailViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    //admob
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
}
//admob
@property (nonatomic, retain) GADBannerView *adBanner;

//.m
//admob
@synthesize adBanner = adBanner_;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //admob
    self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.width-66,self.view.bounds.size.height,66)];
    self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"pub-5290085476815648";
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
    //self.adBanner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
    GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
    r.testing = YES;
    [self.adBanner loadRequest:r];
}

//admob
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView
{
    NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AdMob required the following frameworks:

StoreKit.framework

AdSupport.framework

AudioToolbox.framework

CoreGraphics.framework

MediaPlayer.framework

MessageUI.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework

To add framework Select your XCode project -> Select targets -> Build phases -> link binary with binaries

[image]

Make sure you have also added the other linker flag "-ObjC"

Select your XCode Porject -> Selecte targets -> Build Settings -> Search for other linker flag

[image]

Comment: i had already done all this! added frameworks and change the flag but i had to add 1 more framework that is "AudioUnit" because the compiler wanted it, but now it seems he cannot find this framework, even though it's clearly in the list ;( i've edited the question with a pic @muhammad

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good and easy tutorial here

http://www.guyford.co.uk/showpage.php?id=288&page=XCode_IPhone_/_IPad_Development_-_Adding_ADMob_to_your_app_-_Making_Money

worked first time for me...

Make sure that you do a full clean build, and also reset the simulator..

Comment: Please include key information in your answer. links go stale.